# Assigning an Object's Property to Variable

Tags: powershell

In my script, `$queryResult.events` has a property called `SourceFile` (so `$queryResult.events.SourceFile`) and I'm trying to pass this property if `$queryResult.events.event_name = "File Copy"`, etc....

I want these results stored in a variable called `$UniqueUSBFileNames`.  Currently, I'm trying to do this with the following line in my script:

```
$UniqueUSBFileNames += $queryResult.events.event_name.GetEnumerator() |
  Where-Object {$_.name -eq "File Move" -or "File Copy" -or "Save As"}
```

I'm essentially trying to parse through each element of `$queryResult.events`, see if `$queryResult.events.event_name` is "File Move" -or "File Copy" -or "Save As", and if it is, I want `$queryResult.events.SourceFile` to be saved in the variable `$UniqueUSBFileNames`.

I've been at this forever and any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Adding more code as requested:

```
$UniqueUSBFileNames = $null

$UniqueUSBFileNames += $queryResult.events.event_name.GetEnumerator() |
  Where-Object {
    $_.name -eq "File Move" -or 
    $_.name -eq "File Copy" -or 
    $_.name -eq "Save As"
  }

$UniqueUSBFileNames |
  Sort-Object -Unique |
    Out-File C:\Users\hubt\Documents\Scripts\tmp\$USBEvents
```

Just initializing `$UniqueUSBFileNames`, seeing if the current element through the pipeline equals "File Move" -or "File Copy" -or "Save As", and then sorts only by unique file names (so no duplicates) and prints the results to a file. In the end, I need each `$queryResult.events.SourceFile` in `$UniqueUSBFileNames` if `$aqlQueryResult.events.event_name` equals "File Move" -or "File Copy" -or "Save As".

Sorry if that doesn't make much sense, let me know if it needs clarification.

Comment: Post a short example that contains only the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, you're pretty close, so let's start with the direct answer. You are passing the `event_name` property down the pipe, and want to reference a different property. What you really want to do is pass each event down the pipe as such:

```
$UniqueUSBFileNames += $queryResult.events | <more code>
```

So, now that you have the entire event passing down, you filter for just the ones you want in your `Where` statement:

```
$UniqueUSBFileNames += $queryResult.events | Where-Object {
  $_.event_name -eq "File Move" -or
  $_.event_name -eq "File Copy" -or
  $_.event_name -eq "Save As"
}
```

Ok, now you only have the events that you want going down the pipe, and then you use `Select-Object` with the `-ExpandProperty` switch to capture only the value of the property that you're looking for:

```
$UniqueUSBFileNames += $queryResult.events | Where-Object {
  $_.event_name -eq "File Move" -or
  $_.event_name -eq "File Copy" -or
  $_.event_name -eq "Save As"
} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SourceFile
```

To shorten up what has become a pretty long line, you could use `-in` instead of three different `-eq` in your `Where-Object` statement, and use some shorter versions of some of these terms. What I would do is:

```
$UniqueUSBFileNames += $queryResult.events | where {
  $_.event_name -in "File Move", "File Copy", "Save As"
} | foreach SourceFile
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you very much kind internet person!